# Querying SQL Geometry data using Longitude and Latitude

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, mapping

I have downloaded a shapefile from Ordinance Survey website, and imported it into SQL using ShpToSql.exe, here the setup

[image: ShapeFile being loaded using ShpToSql]

This imports fine.

Now i want to query what region a particular longitude and latitude is within.

Using the following

Postcode: WD25 7LR (Harry Potter Studios :D)
Latitude: 51.6910751568794
Longitude: -0.418128358906299

I thought i could write something like

```
DECLARE @g  geography
set @g = geography::Point(51.6910751568794, -0.418128358906299, 4326)

select [name] from region where @g.STWithin(geom) is not null
```

But that returns an error message of `Operand type clash: geometry is incompatible with geography`

So i tried to change the data type to `geometry`, so code looks like this

```
declare @g  geometry
set @g = geometry::Point(51.6910751568794, -0.418128358906299, 4326)

select [name] from region where @g.STWithin(geom) = 1
```

But no results are returned.

Can someone help me with this please.  Just want to know if a longitude and latitude is within a particular POLYGON.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to import the .shp file using Geography data type, but this gives an error message when i try to import it

[image]

And even if i still try to import it, i them get a message like this for every shape in the shp file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will not allow comparisons between [geometry and geography data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-types-overview?view=sql-server-2017).

If you are not concerned with being exact, you could perform your original query with the point as a geometry type. This will work reasonably well in most small cases where you aren't comparing odd shapes and across hemispheres.

```
DECLARE @g  geometry
set @g = geometry::Point(51.6910751568794, -0.418128358906299, 4326)

select [name] from region where @g.STWithin(geom) is not null
```

Otherwise you will need to import the data as a geography type and based on your note there might be some malformed data in the shapefile.